# How to get a PIL.Image object from cv2.imread? "Unrecognized image mode" error

Tags: python, image, opencv, python-imaging-library

I'm trying to convert an image I get from `img = cv2.imread(path)` to bytes. So I used this:

```
def get_bytes(img):
    result = PIL.Image.fromarray(img, 'BGR')
    bio = io.BytesIO()
    bio.name = 'result.jpeg'
    result.save(bio, 'JPEG')
    bio.seek(0)
    return bio
```

but it gives me an "Unrecognized image mode" error in function `fromarray` in line 2.

The image is not None or something. 
img.dtype = uint8

Comment: 'BGR' is unrecognized mode. Use OpenCV `img = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)` to convert from 'BGR' to 'RGB' then call `result = PIL.Image.fromarray(img, 'RGB')`.

Comment: @zindarod Please don't answer in comments.

Comment: @zindarod thank you!